# AVPlayer is not playing audio

Tags: swift, avplayer

I am trying to play a url audio file picked with `MPMediaPickerController` and attach an observer on the `player` object. I don't know why the player is not playing the audio file, there is no sound output on the device and there is no error shown.

```
var timeObserverToken: Any?

 func addPeriodicTimeObserver(url: URL) {

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.play()


    // Invoke callback every half second
    let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.5,
                          preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))

    let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
    timeObserverToken = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: mainQueue) { [weak self] time in

            //it is never called
            print("time is \(time)") 
     }
   }//end addPeriodicTimeObserver
```

Comment: @AhmadF I get only the print in the console `time is CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 1, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)` , but there is no sound playing. See https://imgur.com/a/b4N7n0f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `AVPlayer` as a *global* variable inside your class/struct. So, remove `player` from `addPeriodicTimeObserver` function and declare globally.

The reason behind this is:

*Local variables* (variables declared inside the function) get deallocated **once the function returns**; In this case, `player` gets deallocated *before* even playing.

*Instance variables* (variables declared inside the class scope) get deallocated **once the class instance get deallocated** (unless there is a retain cycle).

<sub>In case of using a real device for testing, make sure that its not in silent mode</sub>