# Why should I declare custom dataSource object as stored property?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use custom dataSource object for my tableView:

```swift
class MyDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
  // ...
}
```

It works fine in this code:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! 
  // Declare as stored property
  let dataSource = MyDataSource()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = dataSource
  }
}
```

But tableView doesn't show anything (= `MyDataSource` method not called) in this code:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! 

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Declare as local variable
    let dataSource = MyDataSource()
    tableView.dataSource = dataSource
  }
}
```

My questions are:

- Why I should declare `MyDataSource` as stored property?
- If I use local variable, when does my tableView lose dataSource?

Comment: Here is an explanation for same concept issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53727818/5501940

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is, that if you declare data source constant in `viewDidLoad`, your table view has reference for your custom data source just as long as code inside this method runs. So when `viewDidLoad` returns, then data source is lost.

Comment: Btw, I’m trying to explain it how I understand it, so if you have any improvements, feel free to let me know

Comment: You are correct. The reason for this is that tableview stores its datasource as weak reference. So someone (viewcontroller, for example) shall store a strong reference to it.