# How to subscribe method into button touch outside of class that contains this method?

Tags: ios, swift, event-handling

I have `SomeViewController` with a single button on the view. In `didLoad` I add method from the object as the handler of button touch in the following way:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

   func didLoad() {
     // ...
     let x = X()
     button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(x.test), 
                      for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
     // ...
   }

   class X {
     @objc func test(sender:UIButton) {
        // ...       
     }
   }

   @objc func test(sender:UIButton) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

I am Swift newcomer and have no experience with Objective-C. But when I found out that button touch calls `SomeViewController.test` that broke my expectation based on my previous experience in other programming languages. As for me, it looks like a bug. After deleting `SomeViewController.test`, button touch throws the exception:

> 2019-03-07 13:07:25.737090+0200 myProgram[13570:283951]
>   -[myProgram.SomeViewController testWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbcc9d174d0 2019-03-07
>
> 13:07:25.745918+0200 myProgram[13570:283951] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[myProgram.SomeViewController testWithSender:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7fbcc9d174d0'

What is the principle of subscribing to an event with wrapper `#selector`?
How to subscribe method into button touch outside of class that contains this method? If it isn't possible - Why?

---

swift 4.2

Comment: What's the magical part of it?! "But when I checked that button touch called SomeViewController.test that broken my any understanding of programming languages." Ha! why?! `SomeViewController.test` because `test` class is declared *inside* the scope of `SomeViewController` which means it is a [*nested*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/NestedTypes.html) class.

Comment: In addition, this might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727598/avplayer-is-not-playing-audio/53727818#53727818

Comment: "Ha! why?!" Maybe because I'm from OCaml/Java/C# world and never found that `x.test` isn't `x.test` =)

Comment: Well, its not about `x.test`, its about the `target` parameter in [addTarget(_:action:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) method.

Comment: I reproduced the same behavior with not nested X. Also when the target is correct  - it calls SomeViewController.test in both cases (when X is nested and not) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(x.test), 
                  for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
```

with

```
button.addTarget(x, action: #selector(x.test), 
                  for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
```

As the target should contain the implementation of the selector method. Also, there is necessary to protect `x` from garbage collecting, it's better to make

```
let x = X()
```

an instance variable

Comment: Replaced. Continuously have  `SomeViewController.test` call in the first one case and have no call in the second one (when SomeViewController.test is missing) but without exception (touch of the button does nothing).

Comment: "Also it's better to make `let x = X()` an instance variable". I didn't catch. What do you mean to do `x` member of  `SomeViewController` or `var`? `var` didn't help. And I can't do `x` member of  `SomeViewController` in my real situation (the current question was simplified to extract the main essence).

Comment: It is necessary to do `let x = X()` member of class. It fixes the problem. I can't understand the principle. For me, it looks like magic.

Comment: when you define it inside `viewDidLoad` it's local variable that deallocated once method ends hence the target will be nil and the action won't be called that's why you need it an instance variable

Comment: In the real situation, I have multiple `x`. I subscribed local 'x' into the event and saved it in the array that is the member of `SomeViewController`. It works fine. As I understand it now: Link to the object in array protects `x` from garbage collecting. Objective-C proxy is out of garbage collector links counting algorithm.